# Asp.Net. Finding Minimum date from the dataset

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch the minimum date from the dataset but the code is not giving the minimum date at various times.. Please suggest me some way..

```
Report.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Compute("MIN([" + c.ColumnMap + "])", "").ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code -

```
 DateTime minDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
    DateTime maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (string dateString in StringDates)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
        if (date < minDate)
            minDate = date;
        if (date > maxDate)
            maxDate = date;
    }
```

OR

```
 //Retrieve Minimum Date
    var MinDate = (from d in dataRows select d.Date).Min();

    //Retrieve Maximum Date
    var MaxDate = (from d in dataRows select d.Date).Max();
```